Exception MEDIA_EMPTY when send incoming media to other chat using WTelegramClient c#
I modified example listen to update here to send incoming message to other user or chat , here is my code:
public MessageMedia MediaMSG=null;
....
Manager = client.WithUpdateManager(Client_OnUpdate/*, "Updates.state"*/);
var dialogs = .client.Messages_GetAllDialogs(); // dialogs = groups/channels/users
dialogs.Wait();
dialogs.Result.CollectUsersChats(Manager.Users, Manager.Chats);
/***/
private async Task Client_OnUpdate(Update update)        {
           switch (update)
           {                case UpdateNewMessage unm:
                                          await HandleMessage(unm.message);
                                       break;
           }        
}
/***/ 
private Task HandleMessage(MessageBase messageBase, bool edit = false)
{
   switch (messageBase)
   {
       case TL.Message m:
          
           InputPeer peer = null;
           //set peer a value for example user or chat
           //peer =.....
           Task<TL.Message> PostResult = null;
           CancellationTokenSource cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
           CancellationToken cancellation = cancellationSource.Token;
             MediaMSG = m.media;
 MessageMediaPhoto d = null;
 if (MediaMSG.GetType() == typeof(MessageMediaPhoto))
 {
     d=new MessageMediaPhoto();
     d.flags = ((MessageMediaPhoto)MediaMSG).flags;
     d.photo = ((MessageMediaPhoto)MediaMSG).photo;
     d.ttl_seconds= ((MessageMediaPhoto)MediaMSG).ttl_seconds;
     MessageBox.Show(d.flags.ToString() + ":" + d.photo.ID + " :" + d.ttl_seconds+":"+ m.flags.ToString());
     File.WriteAllText("a.txt", d.flags.ToString() + ":" + d.photo.ID + " :" + d.ttl_seconds + ":" + m.flags.ToString());
 
 }
 
 PostResult = client.SendMessageAsync(peer, m.message, d?.ToInputMedia());

 PostResult.Wait(cancellation);
           break;
       case MessageService ms: /*Console.WriteLine($"{Peer(ms.from_id)} in {Peer(ms.peer_id)} [{ms.action.GetType().Name[13..]}]");*/ break;
   }
   return Task.CompletedTask;
}

when the message is text it sent successfully but when it has media for example text and photo i get exception MEDIA_EMPTY,
It is not a specific message but any message with media
the Peer is initialized successful because when incoming message is text message it sent successfully but when incoming message has media it raise exception MEDIA_EMPTY,
the media is not null, even if it null must not raise exception because media is an optional argument and take null by default, the client.SendMessageAsync send media via:
client.Messages_SendMedia(peer, m.media.ToInputMedia(), m.message,Helpers.RandomLong());

i try it directly:
client.Messages_SendMedia(peer, m.media.ToInputMedia(), m.message,Helpers.RandomLong());

but excption MEDIA_EMPTY happans ,i print the media info, the original media is png photo, and media info as this:
d.flags : has_photo
d.photo.ID : 5949672085112603217 
d.ttl_seconds : 0
m.flags : has_from_id, has_media, has_replies

i try to save the media photo to disk :
var filename = $"{d.photo.ID}.jpg";

 var fileStream = File.Create(filename);
var type =  client.client.DownloadFileAsync((Photo)d.photo, fileStream);
type.Wait();
fileStream.Close(); 

but it raise exception FILE_REFERENCE_EXPIRED
i test it in public and private chat but still the same exception
400 
MEDIA_EMPTY 
The provided media object is invalid

please help me to fix it?

Your code is terrible. You need to improve your level in C# before using an advanced library like WTelegramClient.
The ReadMe states:

⚠️ This library requires understanding advanced C# techniques such as asynchronous programming or subclass pattern matching...
If you are a beginner in C#, starting a project based on this library might not be a great idea.

Apparently you recreate an incomplete MessageMediaPhoto instead of just casting the original MessageMedia, this won't work.
See this official example for how to correctly manipulate/download MessageMediaPhoto or MessageMediaDocument:
https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient/blob/master/Examples/Program_DownloadSavedMedia.cs

thanks for help, actually i use another client to send media, may be that is the problem according to answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75439722/telegram-telethon-sharing-media-downloads-across-multiple-different-clients
